# Testing reachability for ip address w/ port

Tags: ios, afnetworking, reachability

I am doing the following:

```
struct sockaddr_in address;
address.sin_len = sizeof(address);
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_port = htons(url.port);
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr([url.host UTF8String]);
self.reachabilityManager = [AFNetworkReachabilityManager managerForAddress:&address];

[self.reachabilityManager startMonitoring];
```

With my URL being something like:
http://10.4.67.32:5959

I have a node server running on that port, however reachability always tells me NO.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Might as well ask...are you on the same local network? If so, have you checked valid port ranges on your firewall?

Comment: Yup, and yup ;).  App works just fine and communicates via that NSUrl with the servers api.  Reachability stills says NO.  Which is wrong.  I must be setting it up wrong or overlooking something.